# OSX: Version of command line tool

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line

Is there a standard way of setting and getting the version of a command line tool built from Xcode > Command Line Tool Template.

Obtaining app version through `NSBundle mainBundle`  does not work with command line tools since there is no Info.plist file by default

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: The convention is to call the tool with `--version` flag, like this: `cc --version`. You need to implement it manually, however.

Comment: But many commands do not implement "--version". There is no hard and fast rule. Ex: "openssl version" and "sed" which does not seem to provide a version.